# Publishing custom dreamweaver form to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, dreamweaver, spry

I created a custom form using dreamweaver cs6 utilizing spry assets, and i'm having trouble publishing this form to wordpress theme.
how would i go about incorporating the 2 together?

Comment: Please post your code and what you have already tried. Are you using Spry for client side form validation?

Comment: i am using spry for form validation, what i tried is copying the form to the wordpress directory along with the spry folder, i tried moving the pictures, then i changed the urls of the pictures and spry to match the new destination. it worked but as a lone page without the theme.

Comment: i also tried copying the code into a new page in my wordpress client, but this broke almost completely, the spry attributes were working quite off, and i couldn't get the pictures to appear at all

Comment: Again, you need to post your code. The most likely thing is that you are not using the correct href for your code, as you need to call the Wordpress function <?php get_template_directory(); ?> but without seeing your code, I can't tell